# Exclude or allow only certain urls using assetlinks.json

Tags: android, ios, android-manifest, deep-linking, android-deep-link

Hello Everybody I am currently working with assetlinks.json trying to exclude urls containing the "/adm/" directory, in IOS I can do this defining into my `https://mysite/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` file this:

```
"NOT /adm/*"
```

example:

```
{
    "activitycontinuation": {
        "apps": [
            "M123DUAQ55.com.totota.rappaporte",
            "M123DUAQ55.com.totota.revisitedoit",
            "M123DUAQ55.com.totota.applictriep"
        ]
    },
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "M123DUAQ55.com.totota.rappaporte",
            "paths": [
                "NOT /blahblah/hack/*",
                "NOT /adm/*",
                "/?????c/*",
                "/index.asp?*",
                "/*/soruce*",
                "/*/video*",
                "/*/operat*"
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

but now I am trying to achieve the same in Android using my `assetlinks.json` file

```
https://mysite/.well-known/apple-app-site-association/assetlinks.json
```

**There´s a way to exclude certain urls using the assetlinks.json file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There´s a way to exclude certain urls using the assetlinks.json file?

No. That is not the role of `assetlinks.json`. `assetlinks.json` ties domains to apps via the signing key fingerprints. It does not tie URLs to apps. Your rules for which URLs to handle would go in your `<intent-filter>` for the relevant activity.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Murphy, I was afraid of this, so I need to configure my rules in the AndroidManifest but I will have to upload a new update of my application if I need to change any rules.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :-) !